# Ignore typehinting for line that already has a pylint ignore

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm wondering how to go about ignoring the mypy error for the following:

```py
# check.py
def add(a, b):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    return a + b
```

running `mypy . --strict` will raise the following:

```
check.py:1: error: Function is missing a type annotation
```

So, how do i ignore typing for this line as well as pylint?

Answer (score 1):

As per [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments), disabling mypy first, then pylance, should work:

```py
def add(a, b):  # type: ignore # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    return a + b
```